# uvm - override virtual task in extended class

Tags: polymorphism, virtual, uvm

I'm writing a checker that extends to my scoreboard. 
For that, I'm trying to override the parser_pkt task with the new one defined in my checker class. This task is called into my uvm run_phase. But, despite the fact I added "virtual" for each of my tasks, I used the same task signature and I used super for my run_phase, this is not working. When I added prints to my two tasks, the code is running the parser_pkt task defined into the scoreboard class.
Why I did wrong?

```
class my_scoreboard_c extends uvm_component;
`uvm_component_utils(my_scoreboard_c)

extern virtual task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
extern virtual task parser_pkt(int a);
endclass

task my_scoreboard_c::run_phase(uvm_phase);
parser_pkt(3);
endtask

task my_scoreboard_c::parser_pkt(int a);
endtask
```

Following my checker class:

```
class my_checker_c extends my_scoreboard_c;
`uvm_component_utils(my_checker_c)

task run_phase(uvm_phase);
super.run_phase(phase);
endtask

task parser_pkt(int a);
endtask 
endclass
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the basics and work our way up.

Are you sure you're instantiating a `my_checker_c` object? You could add a `$display("%p", this)` somewhere (for example at the beginning of `run_phase(...)` to check this.

Comment: I added display in the build phase, run_phase and the check phase. In my log, only the display of the run_phase is not printed...

Comment: @Laura Apparently the `$display("%p", this) doesn't do what I thought it does. I thought it would print the exact type of the object, but I tested it in two different simulators and both gave different results. Try making a small example on EDAPlayground: https://www.edaplayground.com/ with the complete code.

Comment: Maybe using a `$typename(this)` in the task can be useful to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code inside the `run_phase` of your `my_checker_c` class:

```
task run_phase(uvm_phase);
  `uvm_info( get_name(), "YOU SHOULD SEE THIS MESSAGE", UVM_NONE )
  super.run_phase(phase);
  `uvm_info( get_name(), "YOU SHOULD NOT SEE THIS MESSAGE", UVM_NONE )
endtask
```

When is the base class `run_phase` going to finish execution?  Essentially, you are allowing the `run_phase` task of your base class to take over.  UVM's `run_phase` will not finish until all objections are dropped (or a timeout happens).  So you never actually allowed your extended class' `run_phase` to run in your simulation.  Therefore, the solution is to remove the `super.run_phase` call from the `run_phase` of the `my_checker_c` component.